# How/Where do I store the status of a flow for later checking?

Tags: corda

I need to store into the persistence layer the status of a flow for later checking (in particular, if a `FlowException` had been raised). 
How can I do that? Do I need to use the node's storage like the table `NODE_CHECKPOINTS` or are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

This information is not stored by the node currently.

You'd have to subscribe to `CordaRPCOps.stateMachinesFeed` and log the information yourself.